# Restoring missing gems when running Jekyll in Docker

Tags: ruby, docker, docker-compose, jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to run my GitHub Page which is using Jekyll locally on my Windows machine ([code of my page](https://github.com/mu88/mu88.github.io/)).

The Jekyll config `_config.yml` references the following plugins:

```yaml
# all the other Jekyll settings

plugins:
  - jekyll-seo-tag
  - jekyll-sitemap
  - jemoji
```

I follow the [official manual](https://github.com/envygeeks/jekyll-docker/blob/master/README.md) from [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/jekyll/jekyll/) and created the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '2.2'

services:
  jekyll:
    image: jekyll/jekyll:3.8
    command: >
      sh -c "gem install jekyll-seo-tag jekyll-sitemap jemoji &&
             jekyll build &&
             jekyll serve --watch --force_polling --verbose"
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    volumes:
      - .:/srv/jekyll
```

As you can see, at first I have to manually install all dependencies (which are specified in the `plugins` section of `_config.yml`).

When reducing the `command` to `jekyll serve` (as described [in the docs](https://github.com/envygeeks/jekyll-docker/blob/master/README.md#usage-3)), the following error occurs:

```
mu88githubio-jekyll-1  | ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux-musl]
mu88githubio-jekyll-1  | Configuration file: /srv/jekyll/_config.yml
mu88githubio-jekyll-1  |   Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-seo-tag or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- jekyll-seo-tag' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at https://jekyllrb.com/help/!
mu88githubio-jekyll-1  | jekyll 3.8.6 | Error:  jekyll-seo-tag
mu88githubio-jekyll-1 exited with code 1
```

[The docs](https://github.com/envygeeks/jekyll-docker/blob/master/README.md#updating) also mention the command `bundle update`, but this gives me:

```
mu88githubio-jekyll-1  | Could not locate Gemfile
mu88githubio-jekyll-1 exited with code 10
```

What bothers me with my current "solution" is that I have to specify the dependencies/plugins twice, both in `docker-compose.yml` and `_config.yml`.

Is it possible to get rid of this redundancy and make the Jekyll Docker image restore the necessary gems automatically when using `jekyll serve` and using `_config.yml`?

Thanks and have a great weekend!